# NLTK to Identify Names

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, jupyter, nltk

I am attepmting to extract names with the nltk python module.

```
import nltk
#!pip install svgling

nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('maxent_ne_chunker')
nltk.download('words')
```

```
import nltk

from nltk import ne_chunk, pos_tag, word_tokenize
from nltk.tree import Tree

text = "Elon Musk 889-888-8888 elonpie@tessa.net Jeff Bezos (345)123-1234 bezzi@zonbi.com Reshma Saujani example.email@email.com 888-888-8888 Barkevious Mingo"

nltk_results = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
for nltk_result in nltk_results:
    if type(nltk_result) == Tree:
        name = ''
        for nltk_result_leaf in nltk_result.leaves():
            name += nltk_result_leaf[0] + ' '
        print ('Type: ', nltk_result.label(), 'Name: ', name)
```

The output I get from the following code above is as follows:

```
Type:  PERSON Name:  Elon 
Type:  GPE Name:  Musk 
Type:  PERSON Name:  Jeff Bezos 
Type:  ORGANIZATION Name:  Barkevious Mingo
```

This is not correct.  First of all, Some names are broken up.  Farily common ones, too, like Elon Musk.  Next, all names are not identified.  The desired output would be:

```
Type:  PERSON Name:  Elon Musk
Type:  PERSON Name:  Jeff Bezos
Type:  PERSON Name:  Reshma Saujani 
Type:  PERSON Name:  Barkevious Mingo
```

Is there a better option in python?

Answer (score 2):

You could give a try to `Spacy`

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

NER = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

raw_text = "Elon Musk 889-888-8888 elonpie@tessa.net Jeff Bezos (345)123-1234 bezzi@zonbi.com Reshma Saujani example.email@email.com 888-888-8888 Barkevious Mingo"

text = NER(raw_text)


for word in text.ents:
    print(word.text,word.label_)
```

Output:

```
Elon Musk PERSON
889-888 CARDINAL
Jeff Bezos PERSON
345)123 CARDINAL
Reshma Saujani PERSON
```